# adding together two columns from a read file in python

Tags: python

I am working on a project for school and I need to add two columns together from a read file in python and I have tried a lot of different things and nothing has worked. I have two columns

```
 start  
 713866 
 936003 
 937328 
 968012
1004680
1167304
1209211
```

and

```
summit 
 207    
 263   
  46     
 459    
  61     
 154   
 180   
 158
```

How would I add for example (713866 + 207) and get an answer and have python do that for the rest of the list?

Comment: Please show something you think should work, but doesn't. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a homework-answering site.

Comment: We can't just write your code for you. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a start

```
import pandas
colnames = ['start', 'summit']
data = pandas.read_csv('Book2.csv', names=colnames)
```